# Why can't positional arguments follow keyword arguments in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, arguments, parameter-passing

Take the following code:

```
def foo(a, b, c):
    print(a, b, c)

foo(c=3, 1, 2)
```

What I don't understand is why Python doesn't allow this. Python could take the keyword argument and assign it to parameter `c` then assign the rest of the positional arguments to the unassigned parameters which are `a` and `b`.

Why is this not allowed? What's the actual reasoning behind this?

What's even more confusing is that `foo(c=3, *(1, 2))` works. Isn't this essentially same as the call above since the tuple gets unpacked into the individual arguments?

Comment: I don't have a definitive answer ("why" is often hard, but there may be an official spec to quote), but I suspect it's about how to make a robust and intuitive algorithm for deciding where the values end up. For instance what would `foo(2, a=1, 3)` mean? Or `foo(b=2, 3, a=1)`? What if there are too many params, like `foo(b=2, c=3, 1, 4)`. You can probably make up answers for each, but is there a robust algorithm that covers all the edge cases?

Comment: Where can I find information about the algorithm Python uses to match objects to parameters?

Answer (score -1):

as you know, in Python, positional argument passing follow keyboard argument passing, but the problem which you are dealing with is another, you have assigned twice a value to "c" input parameter and there is not any corresponding value for "a" parameter.in general, the error you are facing with is as the lack of corresponding value for "a" parameter.